How to Export IFC to GLTF in Blender with Proper Material Settings
I'm trying to export an IFC file to GLTF in Blender, using Python and the IfcOpenShell library to read IFC data. My goal is to retain the material properties from the IFC file in the GLTF export, especially for objects with transparency (glass) and color information.
Here's the code I'm using:
import bpy
import ifcopenshell
import ifcopenshell.geom

# IFC and GLTF paths
ifc_file_path = "C:/Users/eduar/Downloads/TallBuilding.ifc"
gltf_output_path = "C:/Users/eduar/Downloads/TallBuilding.gltf"

# Blender and IfcOpenShell setup
settings = ifcopenshell.geom.settings()
settings.set(settings.USE_WORLD_COORDS, True)
bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)
ifc_file = ifcopenshell.open(ifc_file_path)

# Create material based on IFC element properties
def create_material(element):
    material_name = element.GlobalId
    if material_name not in bpy.data.materials:
        mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name=material_name)
        mat.use_nodes = True
        bsdf = mat.node_tree.nodes.get("Principled BSDF")
        if bsdf:
            bsdf.inputs["Base Color"].default_value = (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1)
        return mat
    return bpy.data.materials[material_name]

# Collection creation helper
def get_or_create_collection(name, parent_collection=None):
    if name in bpy.data.collections:
        return bpy.data.collections[name]
    new_collection = bpy.data.collections.new(name)
    if parent_collection:
        parent_collection.children.link(new_collection)
    else:
        bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(new_collection)
    return new_collection

# Create objects from IFC elements and assign materials
for element in ifc_file.by_type("IfcProduct"):
    try:
        if hasattr(element, "Representation") and element.Representation:
            shape = ifcopenshell.geom.create_shape(settings, element)
            vertices = shape.geometry.verts
            faces = shape.geometry.faces
            verts = [(vertices[i], vertices[i + 1], vertices[i + 2]) for i in range(0, len(vertices), 3)]
            faces = [(faces[i], faces[i + 1], faces[i + 2]) for i in range(0, len(faces), 3)]

            mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name=element.GlobalId)
            mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
            mesh.update()
            obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name=element.GlobalId, object_data=mesh)

            if hasattr(element, "Name") and element.Name:
                collection = get_or_create_collection(element.Name)
            else:
                collection = get_or_create_collection("Uncategorized")

            collection.objects.link(obj)

            material = create_material(element)
            obj.data.materials.append(material)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in element {element.GlobalId}: {e}")

# GLTF export
bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(
    filepath=gltf_output_path,
    export_format='GLTF_SEPARATE',
    export_texcoords=True,
    export_normals=True,
    export_materials='EXPORT',
    export_yup=True
)


Currently, the material assignment is quite basic and doesn't include transparency or color properties from the IFC file. The export runs without errors, but the GLTF file does not reflect the original IFC materials properly.And I'm currently running it in blender in scripting, but I'm going to create a python script to do this in a listener

It looks like you're off to a good start.  Is there a specific question here?  I don't think the folks on this site are going to "flesh out" your skeleton code for you, but we might be able to help out if you encounter a specific problem or error.
